# Firebase Web SDK - Transaction causing on('child_added', func.. to be called

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

See jsbin.com/ceyiqi/edit?html,console,output for a verifiable example.

I have a reference listening to a database point

jobs/`<key>`/list

where `<key>` is the teams unique number

Under this entry point is a list of *jobs*

I have a listener on this point with

```
this.jobsRef.orderByChild('archived')
                    .equalTo(false)
                    .on('child_added', function(data) {
```

I also have a method that does the following transaction:

```
ref.transaction(function(post) {

    // correct the counter
    if(post)
    {
        // console.log(post);   
        if(active)
        {
            // if toggeling on
        }
        else
        {
            // if toggeling off
        }
    }

    return post;
})
```

When invoking the transaction the `child_added` is also invoked again, giving me duplicate jobs.

Is this expected behavior?
Should I simply check to see if the item has been got before and add to the array accordingly?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: I'm not really clear on the behavior that you're seeing. Can you give a [minimal-but-complete snippet that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Even better would be an (additional) link to a jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem, so that we can see it in action.

Comment: Should calling a transaction cause any listeners to run again? even if in the transaction doesn't change any data

Comment: I think that's possible. Like given how you use .on(child_added) to retrieve data even without changing it.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen How can I use jsbin with firebase without using the database of one of my projects?

Comment: Create a separate project for testing. I use `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com` for most of my tests and share the apikey/url liberally.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen http://jsbin.com/ceyiqi/edit?html,console,output - wait for it to run and get the values from the database, then click the button to run a blank transaction. The child added function returns the data again.

Comment: If you change it to a `value` listener you'll see that it briefly changes the value to `null` when the transaction happens. Then it changes the value back to the original, which explains the `child_added` (which won't see the `null`). I'm not sure why this flap happens, so am asking around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting an interesting edge case in how the Firebase client handles transactions. Your transaction function is running twice, first on `null` and then on the actual data.  It's apparent to see if you listen for `value` events on /jobs, since then you'll see:

1. initial value
2. null (when transaction starts and runs on `null`)
3. initial value again (when transaction runs again on real data)

The `null` value in step 2 is the client's initial guess for the current value. Since the client doesn't have cached data for /jobs (it ignores the cached data for /jobs/list), it guesses null. It is clearly wrong. But unfortunately has been like this for a long time, so it's unlikely to change in the current major version of the SDK.

And because of the `null` in step 2, you'll get `child_removed` events (which you're not handling right now) and then in step 3 you'll get `child_added` events to re-add them.

If you handled the `child_removed` events, you're items wouldn't end up duplicated, but they would still disappear / reappear, which probably isn't desirable.  Another workaround in the current setup is to explicitly tell the transaction to not run with the local estimate, which you can do by passing in `false` as the third parameter:

```
function transact() {
    var path = 'jobs/';
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(path);
    ref.transaction(function(post) {
      return post;
    }, function(error, committed, snapshot) { 
      if (error) {
        console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
      } else if (!committed) {
        console.log('Transaction aborted.');
      } else {
        console.log('Transaction completed.');
      }
    }, false);
}
```

I'm sorry I don't have a better solution. But as I said: it's very unlikely that we'll be able to change this behavior in the current generation of SDKs.